# Difference between Java's Vector.add() and Vector.addElement()?

Tags: java, collections

Please explain the difference between the `Vector.add()` method and the `Vector.addElement()` method, along with a sample code snippet

Comment: I thought it was weird that we had so many questions about Vectors, and then I realized they're all from the same user

Comment: From Google (literally searched verbatim): This method is identical in functionality to the add(Object) method (which is part of the List interface). add(Object) is due the fact that vector implements List Interface and it is appeared since Java 1.2 when Vector was moved to Collections: The collection classes from earlier releases, Vector and Hashtable, have been retrofitted to implement the collection interfaces. addElement is the "original" Vector's method.

Comment: @David, that's a really nice version of LMGTFY -- there's some awesome answers below and your comment isn't really necessary. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links might be a worthwhile read.

Comment: Some anti-LMGTFY policies simply encourage laziness imo. Next time I'll just paraphrase answers that took me 0.2 seconds to Google for and get mad upvotes.

Comment: @David You said that likes it's a bad thing -- if you don't know the answer and you think you can find it via Google, that's exactly what you should do. You get rep, and the OPs problem is solved

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`add()` comes from the `List` interface, which is part of the Java Collections Framework added in Java 1.2. `Vector` predates that and was retrofitted with it. The specific differences are:

1. `addElement()` is `synchronized`. `add()` isn't. In the Java Collections Framework, if you want these methods to be synchronized wrap the collection in `Collections.synchronizedList()`; and
2. `add()` returns a boolean for success. `addElement()` has a `void` return type.

The `synchronized` difference technically isn't part of the API. It's an implementation detail.

Favour the use of the `List` methods. Like I said, if you want a `synchronized` `List` do:

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
list.add("hello");
```

Comment: -1, You didn't spoon feed the entire answer. Sample code wasn't given for the usage of both methods.

Comment: @camickr If you're going to complain keep it to your/my answer and let at least one of the good answers here get upvoted to the top so people searching for this question can find the answer easily instead of wading through nonsense

Comment: @camickr so basically you've retaliated against a (deserved) downvote and compounded a poor answer with even worse behaviour. I seriously suggest you figure out how to interact with people in SO in a mature way (for your own sake).

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't downvote your answer, I was being sarcastic since you answer doesn't answer the question. The answer is "there is no difference, the code is the same". The fact that one returns a boolean value is apparent if you take the time to read the API. If the question was "why are there two methods that do the same thing", or "why does one method return a boolean" then I would have understood that the OP took the time to read the API and was still confused. I don't believe quoting information found in the API helps the poster in the long run. Teach the poster reading skills!

Comment: @cletus I think you are wrong because both functions are syncronized.
`public synchronized void addElement(E obj)`
`public synchronized boolean add(E e)`

Answer (score 6):

The method signature is different, add returns true, while addElement is void.

from http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Vector.java.html

```
  153       public synchronized boolean add(E object) {
  154           if (elementCount == elementData.length) {
  155               growByOne();
  156           }
  157           elementData[elementCount++] = object;
  158           modCount++;
  159           return true;
  160       }
```

and

```
223       public synchronized void addElement(E object) {
  224           if (elementCount == elementData.length) {
  225               growByOne();
  226           }
  227           elementData[elementCount++] = object;
  228           modCount++;
  229       }
```

Comment: Technically true, but not the real reason, since the added return value is hardcoded to true and doesn't tell you anything useful

Comment: Actually, `add` returns `true` (read the code, it *never* returns `false`)

Comment: Thanks yes, only returns true.  But it does return a value while the other is void.

Comment: Neither Vector nor the addElement method is final.  Thus Vector can be extended and addElement can be overridden.  In theory at least, an extension could have totally different behaviour (including a useful return value).  If they wanted to enforce that addElement is equivalent to add, they should have written it thus:  public final synchronized addElement ( E object ) { add ( object ) ; return true ; }

Answer (score 5):

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement(E)) mentions that:

> public void addElement(E obj)
>
> This method is identical in functionality to the add(E) method (which is part of the List interface).

The reason they both exist is (from the same javadoc):

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework.

`List` has an `add` method, so an implementation was added to `Vector`, but to maintain backwards-compatibility, `addElement` wasn't removed

Comment: -1, for spoonfeeding and answer that is found in the API for the method description.

Comment: @camickr ...are you serious? You're going to downvote my complete answer because you're upset over the argument on your "RTFM" post?

Answer (score 1):

**addElement**

> *This method is identical in functionality to the add(Object) method (which is part of the List interface).*

So there is no difference between:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.addElement( new Object() );
```

and

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.add( new Object() );
```

This class ( vector ) exists since Java1.0 and now is pretty much replaced by `ArrayList` which has the benefit of being slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

main difference -> add() will always return true, while addElement() has no return value.

in dept:
addElement(object) method is identical in functionality to the add(Object) method (which is part of the List interface).

add(Object ) is due the fact that Vector implements List Interface and it is appeared since Java 1.2 when Vector was moved to Collections: The collection classes from earlier releases, Vector and Hashtable, have been retrofitted to implement the collection interfaces.

addElement is "original" Vector's method.

found this answer here..
[What is difference between add() and addElement() in Vector?](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article935.html)